# Cannot recover MySQL 5.7 password

Tags: mysql, password-recovery

I installed MySQL 5.7 from terminal and somehow forgot the password I set seconds ago. I am trying to recover it now, however when I execute:

```
sudo mysql_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &"
```

I get the following error message:

```
2018-06-01T06:33:00.696985Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'
2018-06-01T06:33:00.699129Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists
```

Any ideas about how to recover my password?
Is it possible to remove the configuration and reinstall MySQL server from scratch setting a new password?
if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded

Comment: In general, yes, `sudo apt purge mysql-server` should remove all traces of MySQL from your system, so you can start again.

Answer (score 0):

For remove/uninstall and clear all configs correct way it's:

**`sudo apt remove mysql-server --purge`** or **`sudo apt purge --auto-remove mysql-server`**

Then reinstall it: **`sudo apt install mysql-server`**

Comment: do you try to use: mysql_secure_installation  ?